# knockout: remove one element from multiselect control when other is selected

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout and I have a list of item, let say:

```
Tomato,
Potato,
Broccoli, 
Bean
```

all those item are allowed to user to select from multiselect form-control.

```
<select class="form-control" multiple
  data-bind="selectPicker: Types,
  optionsText: 'Name',
  optionsValue: 'VegetableTypeId',
  selectPickerOptions: { optionsArray: AvailableVegetableTypes }">
</select>
```

Except one scenario - when the user selects tomato, potato should unselect. 
I was trying to use subscription on selected items array:

```
this.Types.subscribe(changes => {
        var VegetableTypes = this.AvailableVegetablesTypes();
        var company = VegetableTypes.First(element => element.VegetableTypeId == changes[0].value);
        if (changes[0].status == "added") {
            if (Vegetable.IsTomato) {
                this.Types.remove(element =>
                    VegetableTypes.First(baseElement =>
                        baseElement.VegetableTypesTypeId == element && baseElement.IsPotato));
            } else if (Vegetable.IsPotato) {
                this.Types.remove(element =>
                    VegetableTypes.First(baseElement =>
                        baseElement.VegetableTypesTypeId == element && baseElement.IsTomato));
            }
        }
    }, null, "arrayChange");
```

Problem is that I'm using ObservableArray.Remove, so it's again call my function  before current run is finish. This should not be a problem, because after remove first change is "deletion" type, so whole logic should not be executed.

But after this, when I select tomato/potato again, **nothing is fired.** In the end I actually have both tomato and potato selected. 
Then, when I deselect one of these two and select it again, everything works fine, and then the whole situation repeats.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't understand why you are using `selectPicker` bindings instead of the normal `options` and `selectedOptions` bindings [available in Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html).

However, I built a simple demo which implements the desired behaviour. You can find it here:

http://jsbin.com/fofojaqohi/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Note that, whenever you select Tomato after Potato, Potato will become unselected.

You were on the right track: you need to subscribe to the array of selected items and check if there are any invalid selections. I hope this helps.

For reference, here is the code:

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="true"
  data-bind="options: availableVegetableTypes, selectedOptions: selected">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var availableVegetableTypes = ['Tomato',
'Potato',
'Broccoli', 
'Bean'];

var selected = ko.observableArray();

var unselectMap = {
  'Tomato': 'Potato'
};

selected.subscribe(function(selectedOptions){
  var keysToUnselect = [];
  console.log("Selected", selectedOptions);
  selectedOptions.forEach(function(selectedOption){
    if (unselectMap[selectedOption] != null) {
      // This key exists in the unselect map
      // Let's check if the value is in the array
      if (_.contains(selectedOptions, unselectMap[selectedOption])) {
        // The invalid key exists. Let's mark it for removal.
        keysToUnselect.push(unselectMap[selectedOption]);
      }
    }
  });
  if (keysToUnselect.length > 0) { 
    console.log("Unselect", keysToUnselect);
    var reject = function(v){
      return _.contains(keysToUnselect, v);
    };
    filteredSelectedOptions = _.reject(selectedOptions, reject);
    console.log("Filtered", filteredSelectedOptions);
    selected(filteredSelectedOptions);
  }
});

ko.applyBindings({
  availableVegetableTypes:availableVegetableTypes,
  selected: selected
});
```